# Pages other than Home page not displayed even when URL is good

Tags: urls, 404-error

I installed WordPress on a dedicated server running Debian and each time a create a new page (www.mydomain.com/mynewpage) I can't access it, and when I try I get the error:

Not Found

The requested URL /mynewpage was not found on this server.

Even when I modify it in the WP admin board, If I click "Preview the changes", I get this error. The only page working is www.mydomain.com

Could anyone please help me ?

Thanks for your help

Matthias

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled on the new server?   I would bet it is not by default.  WP requires this for permalinks.  Ck a `phpinfo()` result to confirm.

Comment: I guess I have to look in the 'Loaded modules'in phpinfo() section, so I have:

core mod_log_config mod_logio mod_version prefork http_core mod_so mod_alias mod_auth_basic mod_authn_file mod_authz_default mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_cgi mod_deflate mod_dir mod_env mod_mime mod_negotiation mod_instaweb mod_php5 mod_reqtimeout mod_setenvif mod_status

How do I activate mod_rewrite ?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=debian%20enable%20mod_rewrite&oq=debian%20enable%20mod&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.9401j0j7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking phpinfo(), mod_rewrite wasn't enabled so I enabled it:

http://linuxcommando.blogspot.fr/2014/03/how-to-enable-modrewrite-for-apache-web.html

and it worked !